# How to evaluate $\int \cot^2(x) \;\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you find the antiderivative of $\cot^2x$?

My steps to find it

First

$$ \csc^2 x = \cot^2 x+ 1 $$

because of Pythagorean Identities, so

$$ \cot^2 x= \csc^2 x-1$$
so
$$ \int \cot^2 x\, \operatorname{d}x= \int \csc^2 x\, \operatorname{d}x - \int 1  \, \operatorname{d}x$$

simplying down to

$$\int \cot^2 x = -\cot x- x + C$$

because I know the derivative of $\cot x$ is $-\csc^2 x$.

I want to know if this is the correct solution because I have many gaps in my logic and frequently make errors and I started learning calculus a couple weeks ago.

If I got something wrong can you please tell me my mistakes.

Thanks, Bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is correct. Don't forget $dx$ in the integrals.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really trust wolfram because those answers don't any sense.

Comment: @Bot: If by Wolfram you mean Wolfram Alpha, you can trust any integral it calculates. If it can't do it, it won't show an answer, and if there are caveats on the integrand, it tells you.

Comment: @Bot [The answer from Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cot^2x&lk=4) agrees with yours.

Comment: Thanks, alot for verifying my answer.